# How to parse Array of JSON to array in Swift4 using alamo fire or swiftjson

Tags: json, swift

I need to get all the "students_id" value in the below json and store that in an array.Please tell me the efficient way to do this.Please help.Thanks

```
 {
        "status": "success",
        "user": [
            {
                "student_id": 1,
                "first_name": "Student 1",
                "last_name": "Student 1",
                "emergency_contact_person": null,
                "dob": "0000-00-00",
                "class_section_id": 1,
                "class_section_name": "A",
                "class_id": 1,
                "class_name": "10th"
            },
            {
                "student_id": 2,
                "first_name": "Student 2",
                "last_name": "Student 2",
                "emergency_contact_person": null,
                "dob": "0000-00-00",
                "class_section_id": 1,
                "class_section_name": "A",
                "class_id": 1,
                "class_name": "10th"
            }
        ],
        "response": 200
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried to use search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432834/swift-4-parsing-an-object-array ?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-parse-json-using-jsonserialization

Comment: Your best bet would be to define an appropriate data structure which implements the `Codable` protocol and read your JSON using a `JsonDecoder` Then it is a simple matter to get all student ids. (Sorry, this looks too much like homework to provide code and you did not show us what you tried so far ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `Codable` protocol. Just create a struct that mirrors the structure if your JSON return:

```
struct Response: Codable {
  let status: String
  let user: [Student]
}

struct Student: Codable {
  let student_id: Int
  let first_name: String
  let last_name: String
  let emergency_contact_person: String?
  let dob: String
  let class_section_id: Int
  let class_section_name: String
  let class_id: Int
  let class_name: String
}
```

From there, you'd use `JSONDecoder` to decode your JSON and then extract the IDs you need from it using `map`:

```
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
var studentIDs: [Int] = []
if let jsonData = jsonData {
  do {
    let responseStruct = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
    studentIDs = responseStruct.user.map{$0.student_id}
  } catch {
    print("\(error): \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}
```

Here's a link to a [post re: decoding JSONs in Swift 4](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/).

If you don't need everything from the JSON, then you could just abbreviate your structs to parse only the elements you need. In this example, you could abbreviate your struct to something like this:

```
struct Response: Codable {
  let user: [Student]
}

struct Student: Codable {
  let student_id: Int
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for you help.In this line `let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)`     **json** refers to what?.Thanks

Comment: `json` refers to the string containing the initial data.

Comment: Thanks.It works :)

Comment: I need to get all the "subject_name" value in the below json and store that in an array.How to do this type of json for the above answer.Please help.

Comment: @Suryasps You'll probably want to post a new question. I don't see `subject_name` in the OP.

Comment: i have asked the new question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300349/how-to-parse-the-array-in-json-in-swift-4).please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `for` loop and iterate through each section under `user`

```
for string["users"].each do |x| # => string has your PARSED json 
    return x["student_id"]
end
```

The code is written in `ruby` but you will have a basic idea of what to do.